# How to use a JSON fetch for login authentication in react native?

Tags: react-native, authentication

I need to do a login authenticate with react native fetching a user in a JSON file like bellow:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    return fetch(
'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatheusCbrl/9504064f6605726886df412681fca376/raw/77666e642ee610cfab0aa690d543b3be2c07ba4e/teste.json'
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        // just setState here e.g.
        this.setState({
          users: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

I trying to do something like this:

```
  _signin = async () => {
    const{username, password} = this.state
    if(username == ""){
      Alert.alert(" ",'Por favor digite a Matrícula')

    } else if(password == ""){
      Alert.alert(" ",'Por favor digite o seu RG')

    } else if (
      username.response === this.state.username &&
      password.response === this.state.password
    ) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('Logado', '1');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Diurno');
      console.log('entrou')
    } else {
     this.setState({ isVisible: true })
      console.log('login inválido');
    }
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

First is not a good pratice put your lifecycle functions as async you should create another async function and call it on your didMount.

```
state = {
  users: []
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetchData()
}

componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
   if (prevState.users.length > 0 && (prevState.users !== this.state.users)) {
      singIn()
   }
}

function fetchData() {
    const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MatheusCbrl/9504064f6605726886df412681fca376/raw/77666e642ee610cfab0aa690d543b3be2c07ba4e/teste.json'
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ users: data})

         })
    .catch(error => console.log('oops run to the hills!!!!', error))
}

function signIn() {
    const [findUser] = this.state.users.filter(user => user.cpf === 'whatever')
    if(findUser) {
        //login
    } else {
        //invalid login
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how to do a login authentication with this JSON file?

Comment: Hi, this is not possible how can i say it before this json file return an array with { name, cpf, chapa} fields and no username or password

Comment: I mean if the text input cpf is equal to some value exist in an array it set true and leave the user logiin.. this is possible or I need another way?

Comment: yes, just use const [findUser] = data.find(user => user.cpf === 'whatever')
if(findUser) {
  // do Something
}